# Adding Custom css file in the wp-uploads directory with custom php functions

Tags: php, css

I need to create a  css file generated with php code in the wp-uploads directory.
For example

This is the code to generate the output
`<?php echo "body{color:red}" ?>`

And saves in the `wp-uploads` directory as the generated css output as a css file.

That means when we go to `wp-uploads/filename.css`

The `filename.css` file must contain  `body{color:red}`

**And if you can't understand the question PLEASE COMMENT**

Comment: I do not understand your question - please take the time to explain clearly the goal and also to show code examples of what you have attempted and the issues you faced - as the moment, I don't believe this question can be answered.

Comment: Thank you you are a good sir !

Comment: You can add extra CSS via the customizer, you don't need to create a file. Likewise if you're doing this as part of a plugin you can store the CSS in an option and display at runtime, a physical file isn't necessary. If the file is always the same just create it as part of your theme or plugin folder